# Can titanium android module read the database created using Ti.Database?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

Database is created (and updated) using `Ti.Database` with titanium code. I have created an android module. Is it possible that the created android module can read the database created using titanium code (using Ti.Database)?

Basically, I want to know what would be the path for accessing the database? Titanium app name 'testApp' and module name is 'testAndroidModule'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Look at how the core module does it, and do likewise: https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/tree/master/android/modules/database/src/java/ti/modules/titanium/database